# Is there a standard for the specification of .prj files?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, standards

We use shape files for data exchange. I've looked at the .prj files: different programs produce different prj files.

Is there a standard how the parameters must be specified in a prj file?

AFAIK the name of the projection (e.g. PROJCS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (zE-N)",…]) can be freely assigned. But I can not believe that the name of the datum (e.g. DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",…]) can be assigned freely too.

I have found no information about this.
Even in [ESRI Shapefile Technical Description](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) there is no information about .prj files.
The [ESRI KB Article 14056 HowTo: Create projection metadata (.prj) files for shapefiles](http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/14056) says: *“You have to use the predefined names for map projection and parameter objects*”. But the article does not specify where to find these predefine names. Does each GIS-company specify  it own names? Or does EPSG specify these names?

Here are a few differences in a section of .prj files (EPSG 4647) between QGIS, AutoCAD Map and spatialreference.org

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't call it a standard, but [ESRI KB Article 14056 HowTo:  Create projection metadata (.prj) files for shapefiles](http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/14056) does demonstrate _their_ method for creating a prj from scratch.

Comment: @RyanDalton - Thanks for the interesting link. But unfortunately my question remains still open (see edited question)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's some information on the [OGC Call for Comments page](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/requests/112) on the new specification for coordinate reference system WKT standard.

The original specification was written by Esri many moons ago for OGC based on the mid-1990s version of the EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset's schema. It was revised and extended by other OGC specifications. Because it was a very loosely defined specification, there arose many, sometimes subtly, different implementations. Over the past two years or so, a new specification has been hammered out. It's currently at ISO for comment.

Although I have some documentation on 'best practices' for writing an Esri-flavor prj string, it's not been published in the documentation.

The [EPSG registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org) can now export WKT for its objects based on this new specification. Here's WGS 84, geographic 2D CRS, as a sample:

```
GEODCRS["WGS 84",
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
    ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]],
  CS[ellipsoidal,2],
    AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[1]],
    AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[2]],
    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252],
  ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

Existing WKT should be able to be read by a 'new' parser, but the converse won't be true. Some changes to note:

- Top-level keywords have changed to enable parsers to quickly identify
  the new format
- More elements of the schema are supported (like axis
  directions and ordering)

> Update 6 July 2016: The CRS WKT specification/standard has been
>   approved by ISO and OGC in 2015. The OGC version is
>   [here](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wkt-crs).

Disclosure: I work for Esri and helped write that first OGC specification, was a member of the group that hammered out the new specification, and is a member of the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG registry.

Comment: This is a very clear answer, as scary and evident as the sentence "Because it was a very loosely defined specification, there arose many, sometimes subtly, different implementations" is. What is the current status of the new standard with ISO?

Answer (score 2):

The names you marked are truely free to use, because the relevant data is in the following parameters. The .prj file has to be in WKT format, as explained here:

http://www.geoapi.org/3.0/javadoc/org/opengis/referencing/doc-files/WKT.html

Those keywords have to be used **exactly**, but not the names.

Every (good) software looks at the parameters, and makes its own projection definition from it.

Alternatively, EPSG codes can be used (except for the datum shift).