# When are .prj files included with Shapefiles?

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile

I notice that sometimes Shapefiles that I have received contain .prj files. Sometimes they don't. Wikipedia notes that the .prj file is not "mandatory" and that it contains the :

> projection format; the coordinate system and projection information, a plain text file describing the projection using well-known text format

So my question is: why is it sometimes included, and sometimes not? Do newer versions of Esri tools include it, whereas older ones didn't?

Comment: This "Why" question is really directed at the individuals who don't choose to adequately define their data. It has nothing to do with Esri tools.

Comment: So whether a prj file is included is a conscious decision made by the creator of the dataset?

Comment: Well, ***not*** including it certainly is.

Comment: In my experience, inexperienced users/users from a different discipline are generally when I receive a shapefile lacking a *.prj.  Often, I ask for the .prj and .dbf, .shx  files explicitly, or that I expect ~7 files in a "shapefile".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [original and only published version](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) of the shapefile format defines only three mandatory files:

> An ESRI shapefile consists of a main file, an index file, and a dBASE
> table.

Shapefiles were introduced with ArcVIEW 2.0 and it may be that it could not utilize `.prj` files. The `.prj` file itself was already used by ESRI in the [Arc/Info E00 coverage format](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog488/sites/www.e-education.psu.edu.geog488/files/downloads/Arc_Info%20E00%20Format.pdf).

Possible reasons to not use a `.prj` file

- It is not compulsory
- The strings to use in `.prj` are not documented by ESRI, so other vendors have had to reverse engineer them.
- `.prj` is not needed if a user works in a single coordinate system all the time
- Data providers can usually communicate by other means what the correct coordinate system is

In `.prj` files, ESRI is using *Well Known Text* strings that are similar, but not identical to the WKT format defined by the [Open Geospatial Consortium](https://www.ogc.org). As an example, here is the [GDAL source code](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogr_srs_esri.cpp) that tries to make those two definitions to match.

Comment: There's some advice on what's in a `*.prj` on this site at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/114854/115

Answer (score 1):

Shapefiles contain geographical objects (e.g. points, lines, polygons on the globe). The coordinates of these objects in the shapefile are merely abstract numbers without any inherent meaning.

A `.prj` file specifies the meaning of these coordinate numbers. Without a `.prj` file you'd have to guess what those numbers mean (which actually usually works fine, because most of the time they are latitude/longitude pairs in the WGS-84 datum).

So, one would include a `.prj` file either for completeness or if the coordinate system used in the shapefile is not obvious. On the other hand, one might omit a `.prj` file if the recipient can't process them or expects the shapefiles to use a single given coordinate system anyway.

Comment: I wouldn't say that shapefile are in the WGS-84 datum most of the time but it's true that if you work in a specific area in a specific field you tend to mostly get data on a few  recognizable CRS