# Loaded shapefile isn't visible

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, qgis-3

I have a QGIS 3 project with EPSG code 25832 where there are shapefiles and and PostGIS layers.
I added a shapefile consisting of `*.dbf`, `*.qix`, `*.shp` and `*.shx` files. This shapefile was used in ArcGIS before.

There is an attribute table but no map appears in the map canvas.

Answer (score 4):

There is missing a `*.prj` file that contains the projection (see also [When are .prj files included with Shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/260740/88814)). Go back to the data source to get this file.

If that is not possible, manually set the layer CRS (one of the few cases you actually should do that...): `right-click layer/ Layer CRS / Set Layer CRS…`. You have to guess, based on the nature of the data, which one is the correct one. If you now export/save the shapefile, a `*.prj` file will be generated.

Comment: setting the CRS manually doesn't help - I generated a *.prj file but this doesn't help either

Comment: after setting the CRS manually the shapefile is visible but doesn't overlay the other layers, it is depicted in another location

Comment: You have to find the correct CRS. Put a basemap (like OpenStreetMap form XYZ tiles) to see if it is located in the correct place. Maybe the other layer are misplaced, too? What region of the world, what extent does the file have? Can you share the file for testing?

Comment: I put OpenStreetMap and I see the file is located in another place. the other layers are placed well. The file should be placed in the region of Hannover, Germany and I use EPSG 25832.

Comment: So then it must be another CRS valid in the area of Hannover... Where does the data come from? Can you check there in what CRS the data was saved in?

Comment: Actually the CRS 25832 is mandatory for me.

Comment: When loading the file into ArcMap it says that the file doesn't have a projection, the data can be depicted but can't be projected

Comment: If CRS 25832 is mandatory, you should reproject once you got the original CRS. Are you aware of the difference between layer- and project CRS? Without having a look at the data, it's difficult to help then just advice that you try all CRS valid for your area of interest.

Comment: ok, actually I found the prj for the file on another server and now it works, thanks for the advise.